# Keeping bluetooth on in Windows 10 sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, sleep

I'm wondering if there's a way to keep Bluetooth on when Windows 10 enters sleep mode?

(The reason is that my computer's speaker is an Amazon Echo device, and I'd like to avoid the "connected to..." announcement, but that is not possible, so I'm looking for alternatives to prevent my computer from turning Bluetooth off every time it enters sleep mode.)

Comment: Configure your system not to enter sleep mode, your BT device turning off while in sleep mode is by design

Comment: Well, the thing is, it doesn't need to be on all the time, that would just be a waste. Also it's loud (a desktop), so I don't want it to be on unless I'm using it.